# Trying to store scraped data into sqlite3. crawl: error

Tags: python, sqlite, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl and scrape data from the website and after the command in scrapy shell:

```
scrapy crawl crawlerName -o project.db -t sqlite
```

getting the following error:

```
crawl: error: Invalid/unrecognized output format: sqlite, Expected ['xml', 'jsonlines', 'json', 'csv', 'pickle', 'marshal']
```

Any hint how can I make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/RockyZ/Scrapy-sqlite-item-exporter ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up your **pipelines.py** correctly and all the database columns have been created in your database all you need to do is type **scrapy crawl your_crawler_name** on your terminal and data will be populated into your database as specified in your **pipelines.py** file.